# Apply LUT to a video in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lookup-tables

I have a 3d lut data in a unit array intialized as following

```
const lutSize = 32;

const lut = new Array(lutSize * lutSize * lutSize).fill(0);
```

After adding lut values, I want to now apply this 3d lut to a video.

I looked around a lot but didn't find a solution in javascript.